# Validation Failed - Code Coverage Failure

Tags: code-coverage

I wrote this little code to update some field (And no, I can't use worflow or process buider for that)

In the sand Box, **it's working very well** and I overcome one difficulty (Caused by the fact that the WhoID is populated after the trigger) by using a workflow update field that restart the trigger.

```
 1 trigger Updatelookup on Event (before insert, before update){
 2    for (event u : Trigger.new){
 3        u.lookup_contact__c = u.WhoId;
 4        u.Subject = u.Nom_formate__c + u.Raison_visite_formate__c;
 5        }
 6 }
```

The coverage in the sandbox is .... 0% (0/2) but actually, it's working very well ....

When I want to deploy it, I have this error

"":Code Coverage Failure 
Your organization's code coverage is 59%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment. Also, the following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage. 
• Updatelookup ""

And in détails, I have that... If I understand the 2 last point, I have no ideas about the first one because I see no connection with my code. (I have NPSP installed

0 0 WarehouseDataInstall.testWarehouseDataInstall(), Details: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this state, even though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of valid states.: [BillingState] Class.WarehouseDataInstall.createData: line 16, column 1 Class.WarehouseDataInstall.testWarehouseDataInstall: line 91, column 1

0 0 Updatelookup, Details: Test coverage of selected Apex Trigger is 0%, at least 1% test coverage is required

0 0 , Details: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 59%, at least 75% test coverage is required.

If someone can help me with that ... I saw about test class but I have no ideas about how it's working.

Thx a lot

Edit.

Someone helpd me with this code

```
@isTest 
  private class Updatelookup {
  static testMethod void insertNewEvent() {

    Contact objContact = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact');  
    insert objContact; 

 Event objEvent = new Event(Subject = 'Test', StartDateTime = Date.Today(), EndDateTime = Date.Today().addDays(5), WhoId = objContact.Id); 
 insert objEvent; 
  } 
}
```

The code pass the test but only 1/1 I guess because my trigger has 2, I should have 2/2

Comment: "The coverage in the sandbox is .... 0% (0/2) but actually, it's working very well" - This bothers me. It tells me that your piece of code above does not have code coverage. So you would need to first write a test class for your trigger. Then get in touch with the developers of the "WarehouseDataInstall" and let them know about the error in their test class.

Comment: Hi.  Thx:) The thing is that I have no ideas about how to do the test class. I guess it's simple and short because I have only 2 lines of code but .. tutorials and other explanations are not really helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your code you need to have a test class with 2 test methods. In the first method you need to insert a newly created event and then assert that the fields have updated correctly after the trigger fired. In the second method you need to create an event, insert it and then update it. Last you will need to assert if after the update your values in the fields on the event have updated correctly.

For your second problem, it seems you have enabled country and state picklist . Modify your test class or disable the functionally

Comment: The code himself is working well (I tried it).  In the first step it copy WhoId to u.lookup_contact__c.  After that, I have a workflow that populate Raison_visite_formate__c and then, the triger start a second time (Because of the update made by the workflow) and fill up the Subject.